# IIS Reverse-proxy and URL-Rewrite to rewrite URL to another folder in another internal webserver

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

Please, give me some advices how to implement the following by creating a URL-Rewrite rules.
On the same machine I have:

```
 1. IIS with "mysite.ddns.net/xxxxxx/" accessible via internet
 2. uTorrent with WebUI "192.168.0.5:8080/gui/" which is accessible only via LAN.
```

I made following rules:

```
<rule name="root to xxxxxx" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/xxxxxx/" />
</rule>

<rule name="http to https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>

<rule name="ReverseProxy_uTorrent_Inbound" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^utorrent/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.0.5:8080/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
    <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
    </serverVariables> 
</rule>
```

So, to access to uTorrent I need to type `"mysite.ddns.net/utorrent/gui/"`
But it would be more comfortable to me to enter `"mysite.ddns.net/utorrent/"`.
I tried to replace the above rule with the following:

```
<rule name="ReverseProxy_uTorrent_Inbound_2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^utorrent/" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.0.5:8080/gui/" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
    </serverVariables> 
</rule>
```

but received very strange answer from the uTorrent

```
"Loading...
About
uTorrent µTorrent WebUI
Developers:..."
```

and so on.

I already searched a lot, but unfortunately, I have not found a solution yet. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but should work:

```
<rule name="ReverseProxy_uTorrent_Inbound" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^utorrent/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.0.5:8080/gui/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
    <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
    </serverVariables> 
 </rule>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I've already tried this rule earlier and it didn't work as it have to.
As I understand how uTorrent WebUI works, it needs to have access to the root directory, i.e. in my situation to http://192.168.0.5:8080/ but when I use the rules mentioned above IIS permanently redirects any attempts to access root to '/gui/' subfolder.

Comment: Is it possible to make such a rule that rewrites `mysite.ddns.net/utorrent/` to `http://192.168.0.5:8080/gui/` but uTorrent WebUI still will have access to `http://192.168.0.5:8080/`?